# elasticsearch nested array of objects - complex query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Ok, here is my problem:
At backend I have java spring boot, with mongodb and elasticsearch.
I have documents structured like this in my elasticsearch:

```
{ "id": 1,
  "prefixes": [
    {
      "prefName": "RS",
      "value": "c"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "99c",
      "value": "c"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "RT",
      "value": "a"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "001b",
      "value": "a"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "DT",
      "value": "m"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "001c",
      "value": "m"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "001d",
      "value": "b"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "RN",
      "value": "16"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "001e",
      "value": "16"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "BN",
      "value": "2-228-32590-2"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "010a",
      "value": "2-228-32590-2"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "SS",
      "value": "d"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "100b",
      "value": "d"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "PY",
      "value": "1975"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "100c",
      "value": "1975"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "LA",
      "value": "fre"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "101a",
      "value": "fre"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "CO",
      "value": "fra"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "102a",
      "value": "fra"
    },
    {
      "prefName": "KW",
      "value": "Ekole et psychologie individuelle comparee"
    }] }
```

From client app I'm passing object with this structure:

```
{
"pref1": "(prefixName - value)",
"pref2": "(prefixName - value)",
"pref3": "(prefixName - value)",
"pref4": "(prefixName - value)",
"pref5": "(prefixName - value)",
"text1": "(prefix value - value)",
"text2": "(prefix value - value)",
"text3": "(prefix value - value)",
"text4": "(prefix value - value)",
"text5": "(prefix value - value)",
"operator1": "(logical OR,AND,NOT)",
"operator2": "(logical OR,AND,NOT)",
"operator3": "(logical OR,AND,NOT)",
"operator4": "(logical OR,AND,NOT)"
}
```

So, I have 5 optional prefixes to chose( pref1, pref2... for example RS, RT..),
text fields are their values and should be matched by phrase prefix. The problem is that I have 4 logical operators that links those queries. Can someone direct me how to structure adequate elasticsearch query to fulfill these needs.

Comment: well i still didn't get what are these logical operators and how the combine with the prefix values. can you show some example you tired so far to get this

Comment: I've posted img of search form and explanation what query should do :)

Answer (score 0):

[Search form img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5hIh.png)

Here is the search form and the result should be documet which:
Has prefix AU - Sheakspeare* AND prefix 041a - 99c OR prefix RN - 23 AND prefix LA NOT 23.